# Parsing values in params argument to request.get() which contain periods

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I am using the python package requests to make a get request to a server.  My goal is to replicate certain known http requests and incorporated them into my python script.  The original query string contains one key-value pair 'version=0%2E12' which I know is the url encoded equivalent of 'version=0.12'.  Below is an example of what I am doing to replicate the http request.

```
params = {
          'version'='0.12',
          'language'='en',
          ...
          }
 resp = requests.get(url, params)
```

The resulting url query string has 'version=0.12' in it.  If I try to change the setting of params to the following,

```
    params = {
          'version'='0%2E12',
          'language'='en',
          ...
          }
```

but the resulting query string contains 'version=0%252E31'.  Essentially, requests is parsing the % to be url encoded.

How can I get requests to parse my params arguments with periods properly without manually writing the entire url?

Comment: `.` is a perfectly valid character in a URL-encoded value. Why do you *have* to have it encoded?

Comment: The original query string contains the %2E character and I want to reduce any errors that could crop up from making my requests different.

Comment: Do you *have* an actual error?

Comment: Yes. The server sends back a 200 response code but the return body contains errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `.` is a perfectly valid character in a URL-encoded value.

You'd need to encode the values yourself, bypassing the standard encoding. I'd use `urllib.urlencode()`, then replace the `.` characters by `%2E` by hand.

You then have to append the encoded string as a query parameter to the URL, and configure `requests` to not re-encode the values:

```
params = {
      'version'='0.12',
      'language'='en',
      ...
      }
params = urllib.urlencode(params)
params = params.replace('.', '%2E')
resp = requests.get('?'.join(url, params), config={'encode_uri': False})
```

The `encode_uri` parameter set to `False` does the trick here; it's this [`requests` default](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests-defaults) that otherwise will re-encode the whole URL to ensure RFC compliancy.

Comment: When I try to implement your solution I have an interesting result.  Just before the request.get() call params has the correct '%2E' but once I watch the request go through in Fiddler2 I see that it is changed back to '.'.  Do you know if having a period in the query string is an issue?

Comment: Maybe, however the original http request (also viewed in Fiddler2) has the %2E encoding.

Comment: @JonathanV: Found it; I ran through the code with a debugger, and `requests` is indeed re-encoding the full URL. There is a switch for that though, added to the answer.

Comment: this doesnt work with version 1.04 of requests module i get request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config' any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: @user1582112: Requests 1.0x is heavily refactored. It may well have broken this approach, yes. It *could* be that it doesn't re-encode at all now.